# Real number in FSA table

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I am doing a FSA table for a parser. One of the specs is a real number that must have a digit on both sides of the period. i.e. 1.1 which makes complete sense. My question: is the table below correct? I'm pretty sure it is but if it is not what should I add/subtract to make it correct? Thanks for the help.

Here is the relevant part of the table:

```
state   token   ws  letter  digit   .
  0        0     0     1      2     3
  1     id_tk   -1     1      1    -1
  2     int_tk  -1    -1      2    -1
  3     real_tk -1    -1      3    -1
```

If more of the table is needed, please let me know and I will edit this post.

Comment: You seem to think that there is some standard way of representing finite state automata as a table that the rest of us can recognize. There isn't. You'll need to expand your question to explain your table.

Comment: Draw a diagram :) (I think you have state 2 going to -1 on `.`, it should go to 3)

Comment: @Matt yah, I just realized I am incorrect and pretty much have the correct way now. I had the diagram in my head and followed it wrong. :)